# HTML Transformation Limitations: "iOS Alarm Clock"-like Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, frameworks, css-transforms

For my website, I wanted to achieve an effect inspired by the Apple iOS alarm clock animation:

[image: iOS alarm clock animation]

More specific, the effects I want to achieve are:

1. Styling according to screen position (same style on top and bottom, transition to style in the center)
2. Upscaling in the center, downscaling on top/bottom (as if content was closer to the viewport in the middle)
3. Rotation along the x-axis (on top/bottom, in center no rotation)

How I want these effects to look visually:

[image: sketch of desired transformation]

As you can see in this gif, I kind of achieved those effects:

[image: animation on my website]

My solution uses a [GSAP Scroll Trigger](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/) on **each** element (i.e. every card, dot and so on).
Every element is then animated relatively to the scroll position with CSS transform functions:

```css
// Start point on bottom of screen
filter: brightness(0.8);
transform: perspective(1400px) rotateX(-30deg) scale(0.9);
// End point in center of screen
filter: brightness(1);
transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0) scale(1);
```

Of course, this priciple of animating each element one by one has many drawbacks.
So my question is: are there simpler ways to achieve a similar or even better effect?
Primarily I would be interested in solutions where the parent conatiner of all those elements is transformed, rather then transforming them one by one.

1. As far as I understand, this is not possible with plain CSS [transform functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function), is it?
2. Are there any tricks which could be leveraged to achieve such a transformation
3. Is there a JS/HTML library that could be used for this?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulie_D I do not only ask those questions, I'm also curious if I understood the limitations of CSS transforms and if there are any hacks to make it work

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Paulie_D where could I ask it instead?